# phpmyadmin database getting deleted automatically

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I am using aws ec2 t2 instance. Where I created few database as per my requirement.

For last few day I noticed new databases which I create getting deleted automatically. Is there any possibility of automatically getting deleted?

Current I have not put any password on phpmyadmin. Also no one other then me knowing IP of this server.

Any clue why it is getting deleted and tips to secure it?

Comment: "also no one other then me knowing IP of this server"  thats not true. If its a public ip, its there for everyone with a port scanner tool.

Comment: @MrZach: Yes, i just checked, someone created new databse in it with Warning that they have deleted all database and asking for bitcoin. How do they attack and how to secure from them, any idea?

Comment: Two key things 1) Change the database admin user / password 2) Ensure that no-one on the internet can access the database using security groups. AWS or security training would help.

Comment: A single actor can scan every IPv4 address on the Internet in a few hours. You cannot rely on "no one other then me knowing IP of this server". Automata will try to break in every hour of every day. You have to be secure from the first moment you start your server.

Comment: @user3449212 If the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault way of saying Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Thoroughly read **[Making MySQL Secure Against Attackers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/security-against-attack.html)** and implement the recommendations.
2. **Restrict access to the EC2** through **Security Group**

   - Only permit access to the database (port 3306) from the IP addresses where your web application lives (if it's on the same server don't open access to port 3306 at all).
   - Only permit access to *phpMyAdmin* and *SSH* **from your IP** (e.g. your home connection).
3. **Set password** for *phpMyAdmin*
4. Use HTTPS to access *phpMyAdmin*, e.g. use free **[LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)** certificate.
5. Consider using **[Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/en/phpmyadmin/)** which is similar to *phpMyAdmin* and enforces some basic security.
6. Read or **get some training** about security essentials - both general and cloud-related.

Hope that helps :)